# What characters can't a regex expression start with?

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a short script that will use a string either as a regex expression or as a dictionary key. I would like to keep all of this data in the string, though, without needing to specify in another variable which one of the two it is.

I have decided to use the first character of the string to specify whether it is a regular expression or a dictionary key. Because I do not *think* it is possible to begin a regex with `?`, I used that.

```
tests = (
    r'\d+',
    '?test'
)

values = {
    "test": "Success!"
}

for test in tests:
    if test.startswith('?'):
        print(values.get(test[1:]))
    else:
        print(re.match(test, '123').string)
```

Am I correct in assuming that a regex may never start with the `?` character? What other characters (that appear on a QWERTY keyboard) can never start a regex?

Comment: How about using some prefix for _both_, e.g. `"Dtest"` and `"R\d+"` and removing the first char when using it as a regex?

Comment: you can use `\?` to escape it

Comment: The regex metacharacters are `. ^ $ * + ? { } [ ] \ | ( )`.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good time to revisit your decision (as @tobias_k already pointed out) it looks more promising to either tag both species, thus you have a clear gap less algorithm for deciding or manage the type externally (via an attribute field or the like. In any case you will have a schema one way or the other. Better is clean, symmetric and "gap less" (algorithmic) so you will have no surprises late in the life span of your application. But then it has something cool, to only tag one species ... I am undecided from what I know about the usecase.

Comment: I guess your assumption is correct. If that is the case you can use all quantifiers because they would need to be escaped. Therefore `+`, `*` and `{` should also be possible.

Comment: @JaredGoguen ... but a `.` is a perfect first character in a regex string ;-) like `^`, `[`, `\ ` and `(`, aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the repetition characters (`?`, `*`, `+`) would be a good choice here, since they must be preceded by some other pattern. `$` can only be used at the end of a nontrivial regex, so it would also be a good choice. `}`, `]`, and `)` must follow their opening equivalents, so could also be used.

Comment: But couldn't there be some "forgiving" regex parser that go "well, that can't the be regex meta character `]` in this first position, so I just assume it to be a literal `]`"? EDIT: In fact, Python's `re` module seems to do exactly that... `*`, `?` and `+` seem to work, though, but is there a guarantee? Some "official" regex specification to quote?

Comment: Sure, Python might accept regexen with such oddities, but it's not like you can't live without them.